# Why can't I link my domain with Google Cloud Messaging for Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-search-console

I'm unable to link my domain under APIs & Auths->Push->Configure webhook notifications for android in the Google Developer Console and I'm not sure why.
It asks you to enter the domain after you've linked it within Google's Web Master Tools. 
I've linked it but I still get an error saying:
*Error
You do not have access to the following domain: www.omniru.com*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to input a `complete URL`, make:

`www.omniru.com`

to:

`http://www.omniru.com` or add your port code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google finally updated their webpage and it came with new instructions.

The reason why it wasn't working before is it requires HTTPS. My website was verified as HTTP only in Google's Web Master Tools. Once I verified it as HTTPS I was able to add it without any problems.